# Load Balancer initial request capacity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm using an AWS ALB LoadBalancer, and I was curious about the initial request capacity that can be handled by the ALB without scaling?

The reason behind this is that I need to pre-warm up my load balancer or not

Answer (score 1):

The ALB itself doesn't require/offer scaling. How many instances of your application need to be running depends on your application, not on the ALB. So the answer to your question is really for you to answer, based on what you believe your application can handle.

Comment: Then what does pre-warming up the load balancer means?

Comment: It's unlikely you should need to do that. If you do, you'll have to contact support: https://aws.amazon.com/articles/best-practices-in-evaluating-elastic-load-balancing/#pre-warming